# Authentaction mode based on IP?

Tags: authentication, iis, iis-8.5

Is it possible to allow `anonymousAuthentication` for requests from the local network (10.0.0.X), but disallow it, and force `windowsAuthentication` for any other users?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only If you write an IIS module to extend the functionality. The builtin features won't allow you to achieve this.